# Refreshing an edited question while editing still alerts of changes on navigation

Tags: bug, edits, notifications, notification-bar

There's a small bug when you're editing a question and the question is refreshed by the "an edit has been made to this post; click to load" message. If you do not go back and edit the question again and save, you will still get the

> Confirm Navigation
>
> You have started writing or editing a post...

alert when navigating away from the page. Since your edits aren't saved in any fashion (or remembered by the editor), expected result would be that the alert does not display.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Begin editing a post
- Wait for it to be edited by another member
- Refresh the post by clicking on the banner that is shown
- Navigate away from the page
- Alert is displayed

I would imagine that this could affect editing answers as well.